# Spring Cache Exception: io.lettuce.core.RedisCommandExecutionException: ERR wrong number of arguments for 'set' command

Tags: java, redis, spring-data-redis, spring-cache

I use Spring Boot Version: 2.1.4.RELEASE

When I set `spring.cache.redis.time-to-live=20000` in `application.yml` file.I got a exception. What should I do when I want to add TTL in redis cache ?
How to use cache expiration at Spring Cache with Redis?

```java
org.springframework.data.redis.RedisSystemException: Error in execution; nested exception is io.lettuce.core.RedisCommandExecutionException: ERR wrong number of arguments for 'set' command
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceExceptionConverter.convert(LettuceExceptionConverter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceExceptionConverter.convert(LettuceExceptionConverter.java:52)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceExceptionConverter.convert(LettuceExceptionConverter.java:41)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.PassThroughExceptionTranslationStrategy.translate(PassThroughExceptionTranslationStrategy.java:44)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.translate(FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.java:42)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnection.convertLettuceAccessException(LettuceConnection.java:268)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceStringCommands.convertLettuceAccessException(LettuceStringCommands.java:799)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceStringCommands.set(LettuceStringCommands.java:180)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.DefaultedRedisConnection.set(DefaultedRedisConnection.java:281)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.DefaultRedisCacheWriter.lambda$put$0(DefaultRedisCacheWriter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.DefaultRedisCacheWriter.execute(DefaultRedisCacheWriter.java:242)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.DefaultRedisCacheWriter.put(DefaultRedisCacheWriter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache.put(RedisCache.java:159)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.AbstractCacheInvoker.doPut(AbstractCacheInvoker.java:87)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport$CachePutRequest.apply(CacheAspectSupport.java:820)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:429)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:345)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
    at top.yunshu.shw.server.service.group.impl.GroupServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$815b195d.findTeacherAllGroups(<generated>)
    at top.yunshu.shw.server.controller.teacher.TeacherController.lambda$getTeacherCreateGroups$0(TeacherController.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManager.lambda$startCallableProcessing$4(WebAsyncManager.java:323)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: io.lettuce.core.RedisCommandExecutionException: ERR wrong number of arguments for 'set' command
    at io.lettuce.core.ExceptionFactory.createExecutionException(ExceptionFactory.java:135)
    at io.lettuce.core.ExceptionFactory.createExecutionException(ExceptionFactory.java:108)
    at io.lettuce.core.protocol.AsyncCommand.completeResult(AsyncCommand.java:120)
    at io.lettuce.core.protocol.AsyncCommand.complete(AsyncCommand.java:111)
    at io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandWrapper.complete(CommandWrapper.java:59)
    at io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler.complete(CommandHandler.java:646)
    at io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler.decode(CommandHandler.java:604)
    at io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler.channelRead(CommandHandler.java:556)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:359)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:337)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:86)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:359)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:337)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:86)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:359)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:337)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1408)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:359)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:930)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:677)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:612)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:529)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:491)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:905)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    ... 1 common frames omitted
```

I use Spring Boot Version: 2.1.4.RELEASE

When I set `spring.cache.redis.time-to-live=20000` in `application.yml` file.I got a exception. What should I do when I want to add TTL in redis cache ?
How to use cache expiration at Spring Cache with Redis?

Comment: Do you have a solution for this please?

Comment: can you specify the redis version which you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue. I was using redis 2.4.5 version , then after going through this article, I upgraded to 3.0.504 and it worked  ( my os is windows )

https://github.com/microsoftarchive/redis/releases

As explained in this issue : it seems that below redis 2.6.0 , we cannot set the time to live ( ttl )
https://github.com/eiselems/ultimate-redis-boot/issues/1